# Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: instantiate - PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am working on sending some emails and PHPMailer have been working perfectly on my test server.

Now, after i moved it to the production server, none of my mails will fire and i am getting a

Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: instantiate.

I have been googling and toiling with phpmailer to see what seems to be the problem and from what i gathered, i was not able to make a regular php mail() request (this is the var that needs to return true for the error to stop

```
 $rt = @mail($to, $this->EncodeHeader($this->Subject), $body, 
                        $header, $params);
```

But even when setting subject and body to one word and the headers to the simplest kind

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

The mail function still returns false and i am really running out of ideas at this point

Anyone have anything to help me out with? It is getting extremly frustration at this point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending a subject header encoded as `UTF-8`, which the PHPMailer class would reject since it contained a perculiar swedish letter, namely “å”.

Something like that:

```
$subject = utf8_decode("Någon har svarat på din fråga på $site");
```

This converts the string to ISO-8859-1 encoding, which, of course, worked fine.

Comment: I tried to trim all the fat to just get the mail() function to return true. Even when i just put in "test" in $subject and $body it still returned false so doubt it the problem is with the $subject